# Await reaction on bot message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make some kind of poll bot that counts the reactions to a message. The bot sends a message, reacts to it and would count the reaction to his message.

When I'm using `awaitReactions`, the reactions aren't handled in the `then`.

The code is the following:

```
channel.send(mess)
 .then(async m => {
       await m.react(ok);
       await m.react(ko);
       await m.react(maybe);
       m.awaitReactions((r, u) => { console.log(`filter:${u.username}`); return true; }, {max: 100000})
        .then(collected => {
             console.log("Reacted");
             collected.forEach(c => { console.log(c); });
         })
          .catch(collected => {
              console.log("Catch");
          });
});
```

When reacting to the generated message, the only `console.log` printed are the one in the filter function.

Why are the `console.log` in `then` or `catch` not executed?

**Edit:** add return in the function parameter of `awaitRections`. Adding the return doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Does awaitReactions return a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you await reactions, the promise is resolved when one of the parameters you passed in the options object is reached like when the time is up, or the maximum of reactions is reached. If no parameters is reached, the promise is not resolved. In your case, you only give a maximum of reactions (100000), and this will never be reached.

For example, to wait 30 seconds before getting the results of the poll you can do:

```
m.awaitReactions((r, u) => { console.log(`filter:${u.username}`); return true; }, { time: 30000 })
    .then(collected => {
         console.log("Collector ended");
         // Collected is a collection with all the reactions collected
         console.log(collected);
     })
     .catch(collected => {
          console.log("No reaction collected");
     });
```

If you want to do something like in your example, a console.log of "Reacted" when someone reacts, you need to use a MessageCollector instead of message.awaitReactions. You can do:

```
let collector = message.createReactionCollector((r, u) => { console.log(`filter:${u.username}`); return true; });
collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
     console.log("Reacted");
});
```